# View Soap Requests from imported connected service

Tags: visual-studio, soap, asmx

I'm trying to implement a consumer for a 3rd party SOAP service.  I've imported the asmx in as a connected service and able to initialise the client and make requests etc all fine to a point.

Where my trouble begins is a couple of the requests I'm making from all appearances are working correctly and returning me success results but when viewing the results at the other, the data I'm posting is just not there.  I've been speaking to the providers of this SOAP service, and they've asked I send them the requests I'm making.  However, since I'm using the generated SOApClient, I'm not sure exactly how to get the actual request.

Is there away to view the actual SOAP messages?  Did have a look at Fiddler, but couldn't see anything bar the network traffic.

My project is C# .Net 4.8 and working in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: How did you build your client? Service reference? WCF? There should be options in App.config or Web.config to enable logging of the messages.

Comment: Imported the asmx as a connected service via the Add Service Reference.   Sorry if didn't make that clear enough

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing

Comment: @Bogdan certainly did.  Your first comment actually gave me the clue what to google.  ended up on that exact link, between that and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing managed to get enough logging happening to get what I needed.  Drop in an answer if you want a shinny tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be options in App.config or Web.config to enable logging of the messages.

For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing